# java.lang.NullPointerException in Lightadmin plugin

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, nullpointerexception, maven-3, lightadmin

I am trying to integrate [lightadmin](https://github.com/la-team/light-admin/) plugin in my online-test application for CRUD implementation, and facing following null pointer exception.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.apache.tiles.renderer.DefinitionRenderer.isRenderable(DefinitionRenderer.java:64)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView.checkResource(TilesView.java:101)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver.loadView(UrlBasedViewResolver.java:439)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractCachingViewResolver.createView(AbstractCachingViewResolver.java:244)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver.createView(UrlBasedViewResolver.java:402)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractCachingViewResolver.resolveViewName(AbstractCachingViewResolver.java:156)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.resolveViewName(DispatcherServlet.java:1260)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1201)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1005)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:952)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.lightadmin.core.web.DispatcherRedirectorServlet.service(DispatcherRedirectorServlet.java:38)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.lightadmin.core.view.TilesContainerEnrichmentFilter.doFilterInternal(TilesContainerEnrichmentFilter.java:40)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
```

This error is coming when accessing *project/admin* url for lightadmin dashboard. Other parts of web app are working perfectly.
I am using Spring 4.0.4 along with hibernate 4.
I have used maven to include lightadmin dependencies, for others I have imported jars manually.
My code is as follows:

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">

    <display-name>BasicSpringMVC</display-name>

     <context-param>
        <param-name>light:administration:base-url</param-name>
        <param-value>/admin</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>light:administration:base-package</param-name>
        <param-value>org.gdgjss.lightadmin.config</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>light:administration:security</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>


    <context-param>
        <param-name>light:administration:back-to-site-url</param-name>
        <param-value>http://lightadmin.org</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- other  -->


    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>
        <param-value>test-env</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>httpMethodFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>


    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>httpMethodFilter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value></param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/static/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">


    <context:annotation-config />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <mvc:interceptors>
        <bean class="org.gdgjss.service.SessionValidator" />
    </mvc:interceptors>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="org.gdgjss"></context:component-scan>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url"
            value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mcq_portal?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="tilhari" />
    </bean>



    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="org.gdgjss.model" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

     <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
<!--      <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="/gdgmcq/src/persistence.xml"></property> -->
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
      <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
    </property>
  </bean>

  <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
  </bean>



</beans>
```

**Model: Questions.java**

```
package org.gdgjss.model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
@Entity
public class Questions {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer question_id;
    private String question;
    private String optionA;
    private String optionB;
    private String optionC;
    private String optionD;
    private String answer;

    public Integer getQuestion_id() {
        return question_id;
    }

    public void setQuestion_id(Integer question_id) {
        this.question_id = question_id;
    }

    public String getQuestion() {
        return question;
    }

    public void setQuestion(String question) {
        this.question = question;
    }

    public String getOptionA() {
        return optionA;
    }

    public void setOptionA(String optionA) {
        this.optionA = optionA;
    }

    public String getOptionB() {
        return optionB;
    }

    public void setOptionB(String optionB) {
        this.optionB = optionB;
    }

    public String getOptionC() {
        return optionC;
    }

    public void setOptionC(String optionC) {
        this.optionC = optionC;
    }

    public String getOptionD() {
        return optionD;
    }

    public void setOptionD(String optionD) {
        this.optionD = optionD;
    }

    public String getAnswer() {
        return answer;
    }

    public void setAnswer(String answer) {
        this.answer = answer;
    }

}
```

**AdminstrationController for model**

```
package org.gdgjss.lightadmin.config;

import org.gdgjss.model.Questions;
import org.lightadmin.api.config.AdministrationConfiguration;
import org.lightadmin.api.config.builder.EntityMetadataConfigurationUnitBuilder;
import org.lightadmin.api.config.unit.EntityMetadataConfigurationUnit;

public class QuestionsAdministration extends AdministrationConfiguration<Questions> {
      @Override
        public EntityMetadataConfigurationUnit configuration(EntityMetadataConfigurationUnitBuilder configurationBuilder) {
            return configurationBuilder.nameField("question").pluralName("Customers").build();
        }

}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>gdgmcq</groupId>
    <artifactId>gdgmcq</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.lightadmin</groupId>
            <artifactId>lightadmin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0.RC1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Need help !